# Using GOOGLEFINANCE function on google sheets to get historical marketcap

Tags: finance, google

I have a question related to accessing historical data. My first attempt to grab historical data for a few companies was using Google sheets and the *GOOGLEFINANCE* function. Unfortunately, it seems to be fairly limited.

Running this function works very well and I could not be happier:

`=GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "price", DATE(2014,1,1), DATE(2014,12,31))`

But running this one, where I replace price with marketcap does not work:

`=GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "marketcap", DATE(2014,1,1), DATE(2014,12,31))`

If I remove the dates, I am able to get the marketcap today, but it seems historical marketcap is blocked. Is this behind a paywall or something or do they just not make historical marketcap data available?

Thanks for any help.

Also, if there is another way to get historical marketcap data, please let me know!